# Loop through XML and delete every 10th node instance - How?

Tags: .net, xml

I have the following chunk of an XML file-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TenDayWeather>
   <TenDay ID="B3_7187">
     <TenDayData>
        <Day>FRI  9</Day>
        <MinTemp>4°C</MinTemp>
        <MaxTemp>10°C</MaxTemp>
        <Icon>Rain</Icon>
        <IsWeekday>true</IsWeekday>
     </TenDayData>
     <TenDayData>
        <Day>SAT  10</Day>
        <MinTemp>6°C</MinTemp>
        <MaxTemp>15°C</MaxTemp>
        <Icon>Fewshowers</Icon>
        <IsWeekday>false</IsWeekday>
     </TenDayData>
     <TenDayData>
        <Day>SUN  11</Day>
        <MinTemp>4°C</MinTemp>
        <MaxTemp>15°C</MaxTemp>
        <Icon>Fewshowers</Icon>
        <IsWeekday>false</IsWeekday>
     </TenDayData>
     <TenDayData>
        <Day>MON  12</Day>
        <MinTemp>5°C</MinTemp>
        <MaxTemp>14°C</MaxTemp>
        <Icon>Rain</Icon>
        <IsWeekday>true</IsWeekday>
     </TenDayData>
     <TenDayData>
        <Day>TUE  13</Day>
        <MinTemp>2°C</MinTemp>
        <MaxTemp>13°C</MaxTemp>
        <Icon>Fewshowers</Icon>
        <IsWeekday>true</IsWeekday>
     </TenDayData>
     <TenDayData>
        <Day>WED  14</Day>
        <MinTemp>3°C</MinTemp>
        <MaxTemp>14°C</MaxTemp>
        <Icon>Fewshowers</Icon>
        <IsWeekday>true</IsWeekday>
     </TenDayData>
     <TenDayData>
        <Day>THU  15</Day>
        <MinTemp>3°C</MinTemp>
        <MaxTemp>16°C</MaxTemp>
        <Icon>Fine</Icon>
        <IsWeekday>true</IsWeekday>
     </TenDayData>
     <TenDayData>
        <Day>FRI  16</Day>
        <MinTemp>5°C</MinTemp>
        <MaxTemp>16°C</MaxTemp>
        <Icon>Cloudy</Icon>
        <IsWeekday>true</IsWeekday>
     </TenDayData>
     <TenDayData>
        <Day>SAT  17</Day>
        <MinTemp>8°C</MinTemp>
        <MaxTemp>16°C</MaxTemp>
        <Icon>Rain</Icon>
        <IsWeekday>false</IsWeekday>
     </TenDayData>
     <TenDayData>
        <Day>SUN  18</Day>
        <MinTemp>4°C</MinTemp>
        <MaxTemp>13°C</MaxTemp>
        <Icon>Showers</Icon>
        <IsWeekday>false</IsWeekday>
     </TenDayData>
   </TenDay>
   <TenDay ID="B3_11194">
     <TenDayData>

 etc etc, repeats some 250 times with a different TenDay ID


   </TenDay>
</TenDayWeather>
```

This is just one of a heap (250 or so) of of these segments that I need to iterate through and delete every tenth node instance of 'TenDayData'. There are only ten instances of 'TenDayData' in each group so I need to delete the last one each time.

What's the best way to do this?
I'm familiar with dot net childNodes in XmlDocument and XmlTextReader but can't figure out how to differentiate between the 10 child nodes without using a ForNext loop and a counter which doesn't sound like the right way to do it.

Any clues anyone

I use vb.net but can read most c#.

BTW here's the code I was playing with.

```
            Dim reader As New XmlTextReader(fSourceXmlPath & xmlFileName)
            Dim doc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()
            doc.Load(reader)
            reader.Close()

            Dim childNode As XmlNode
            Dim nodeList As XmlNodeList
            Dim iNode As Integer = 0

            nodeList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("//TenDayWeather/TenDay[@ID='B3_7187']")
            Console.Write(nodeList.Count.ToString)
            For Each node As XmlElement In nodeList
                iNode += 1
                If iNode = 10 Then
                    Console.WriteLine(node("TenDayData").InnerText)
                    childNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("//TenDayWeather/TenDay[@ID='B3_7187']/TenDayData")
                     childNode.ParentNode.RemoveChild(childNode)
                End If
            Next

            doc.Save(fSourceXmlPath & xmlFileName)
```

Unfortunately there is never any nodeList.count value.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't get head around linq (thanks scartag) and as I already had a pile of xmldocument code in place, I persevered.
This is what I wound up with -  maybe it will help someone.

```
            Dim iNode As Integer
            For Each xn As XmlNode In doc.SelectNodes("//TenDayWeather/TenDay")
                For Each childNode As XmlNode In xn.SelectNodes("TenDayData")
                    If childNode IsNot Nothing Then
                        iNode += 1
                        If iNode = 10 Then
                            childNode.ParentNode.RemoveChild(childNode)
                            iNode = 0
                        End If
                    End If
                Next
            Next
            Console.Write("Deleted tenth day data." + vbNewLine)
```